# Why my script named "killl" fails, but after renaming works perfectly?

Tags: shell-script, osx

The script in question terminates the latest process on my localhost port 8080.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(lsof -i:8080 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')
kill -9 $x
```

It didn't work, if the script was named 'killl' (get it? Kill Latest?). It gave me a prompt for `cmdsubst>`  Renaming the script to 'asdf', everything works. Is there an explanation for this behaviour? I'm using MacOS El Capitán.

Comment: Do you have another function, alias, utility or other command called `killl`?

Comment: Don't make the names ambiguous. `killl` can be misinterpreted as wrongly spelled `kill`. It's better to be explicit and more descriptive: `kill_latest` or `kill_last`.

Comment: What is the output of `type killl` in the shell where you tried to start it?

Answer (score 28):

`cmdsubst>` is the secondary prompt printed by the `zsh` shell when it's waiting for the end of a command substitution being entered.

If you get that prompt after just entering `killl<Return>`, then the only reasonable explanation is that you have an alias (which is some form of string macro expansion) for `killl` that expands to something that contains an unterminated `$(...)` command substitution, like:

```
$ alias 'killl=echo $(lsof -ti'
$ killl :22
cmdsubst>
```

Where `zsh` is asking you to close that `$(...)` command substitution.

A few more notes:

- the output of `lsof` is sorted by pid. pid numbers are wrapped, a larger pid is not a guarantee that the process was started later.
- `-i:8080` will report TCP or UDP sockets that have the 8080  port as the source or destination port, whether it's a listening, accepting or connecting socket.
- If you want to get the pid only, you can use the `-t` option of `lsof`: `lsof -ti:8080 | tail -n2`
- `kill -9` is `kill -s KILL`, which sends a signal that the application cannot act upon to exit gracefully. It should only be used as a last resort.

To kill the most recently started process that has a socket bound (either end) on port 8080, you could do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
unset IFS
pids=$(lsof -ti:8080) &&
  LC_ALL=C ps -o pid=,lstart= -p $pids |
  LC_ALL=C sort -k6,6n -k4,4M -k3,3n -k5,5 -k1,1n |
  awk 'END{system("kill " $1)}'
```

(assumes GNU `sort` (as found on macOS) and a `ps` implementation that supports the `lstart` column (like macOS' and procps-ng's, though the code would have to be updated for procps-ng where the month and day fields are swapped)).

Answer (score 1):

> It gave me a prompt for `cmdsubst>`

Because when you typed the command you did not type

```
killl
```

you typed

```
killl $(
```

or similar.  This was *nothing to do with* the name of the script, or even that it was a script in the first place.  You could have achieved the same effect with a wholly nonexistent command:

```
Zeick $(
```

The shell's parser was expecting more input to complete the only partly complete command.  Your thinking about the script name is a complete red herring.

Comment: That's a pretty big assumption to say he typed `killl $(` for some reason, and very unlikely that he did so. Stéphane Chazelas' answer is more likely the case.

Comment: If it is indeed due to a typo, then `\`` is more likely than `$(`.

Comment: No, Emil Jeřábek; `\`` is not likely at all since _it does not give the same prompt_.  Try it.  No, Herhtar; it's not an assumption when typing that _or similar_ is _the way to get that prompt_.  It is a deduction.

Comment: You assert that OP "did not type `killl`," when as Stéphane Chazelas explains, it is entirely possible that OP did indeed type `killl`.  Therefore, I have downvoted your answer as wrong.